# Blender with external python script "bpy.ops.transform.rotate.poll() failed, context is incorrect"

Tags: python, import, rotation, blender, bpy

I encountered a problem with blender when I try to start it with an external Python script ("--python import.py"), which should import a blend file and tries to manipulate the rotation and position of an object which is in the blend file.

What do I want to do?
I want to start blender with an external python script to import an unknown number of ".blend"-Files an set the position and rotation of that object in the file.

So my python script "import.py" looks like this:

```
import bpy
import os
import math
 
bpy.ops.wm.append(
    filepath=os.path.join('H:\\Python\\blender\\test2.blend', 'Object', 'Gear'),
    directory=os.path.join('H:\\Python\\blender\\test2.blend', 'Object'),
    filename='Gear'
)

o = bpy.data.objects['Gear']
bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = o
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=3.14/4,orient_axis='Y')
bpy.ops.transform.translate(value=(-4, 2, 5))
```

So in the test2.blend is an object named "Gear". When I start blender with `blender.exe  test1.blend --python .\import.py`. the test2.blend is imported but then I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "H:\Python\blender\.\import.py", line 19, in <module>
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=2.0,orient_axis='Y')
  File "E:\Programme\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.1\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.transform.rotate.poll() failed, context is incorrect
```

When I comment out the line `bpy.ops.transform.rotate` the translate works just fine.
The interesting thing is, when blender opens with the quoted error, I can paste the code 1:1 in the Python console and it works.

I'm using Blender 3.1.2 on Windows 10.

Any Ideas?